# How to get raw binary data from stream using WebRTC native c++ API?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

Hi using the webrtc native c++ API I am able to establish an RTCPeerconnection from my browser to a locally running server. In the PeerConnectionObserver interface there is an OnAddStream callback that gets fired when I add a media stream from my browser to the peer connection. The server fires this callback as expected and and I now have access to the stream on the server. This is where I am stuck, what do I need to do with the stream now to get the raw binary data from it. I have seen some examples using a "VideoSink" after getting the video tracks from the stream but nothing is clear enough and there is no documentation for the c++ api header files. Anyone with webrtc experience familiar with actually doing stuff with the media stream from the native api? Here is where I am stuck

```
class PeerConnectionObserver : public webrtc::PeerConnectionObserver {
 ....
    // Override adding a stream.
    void OnAddStream(rtc::scoped_refptr<webrtc::MediaStreamInterface>stream ) {

      //TODO now that I have the stream what do I do ? 
      std::cout << "OnAddStream " << stream->label();

    }
....
}
```

Comment: That is done by implementing a fake Audio and Video device. Plan for a month or more to have it usable/stable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you have any examples I can look at? Also I didn't quite understand the last part of your reply "Plan for a month or more to have it usable/stable" are you referring to the webrtc team ? @velkan

Comment: Not sure but this may do what you want https://github.com/sourcey/libsourcey